# Haskell quiz: a simple function

Tags: haskell

I'm not a Haskell programmer, but I'm curious about the following questions.

Informal function specification:

Let MapProduct be a function that takes a function called F and multiple lists. It returns a list containing the results of calling F with one argument from each list in each possible combination.

Example:

Call MapProduct with F being a function that simply returns a list of its arguments, and two lists. One of the lists contains the integers 1 and 2, the other one contains the strings "a" and "b". It should return a list that contains the lists: 1 and "a", 1 and "b", 2 and "a", 2 and "b".

Questions:

- How is MapProduct implemented?
- What is the function's type? What is F's type?
- Can one guess what the function does just by looking at its type?
- Can you handle inhomogeneous lists as input? (e.g. 1 and "a" in one of the input lists)
- What extra limitation (if any) do you need to introduce to implement MapProduct?

Comment: I'm guessing this wasn't originally a Haskell question, since there is no such thing as a heterogeneous list in Haskell without resorting to existential types.

Comment: I knew this issue, but I thought one can surely workaround that somehow, isn't that the case? This is a pretty simple and useful function, it is also easy to implement correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- How is MapProduct implemented?

.

```
Prelude> :m + Control.Applicative
Prelude Control.Applicative> (,,) <$> [1,2,3] <*> ["a","b","c"] <*> [0.8, 1.2, 4.4]
[(1,"a",0.8),(1,"a",1.2),...,(3,"c",4.4)]
```

- What is the function's type? What is F's type?

The type of F depends on the list you want to apply. `<$>` here is `fmap`, and [`(<*>) :: f(a->b) -> f a -> f b`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Applicative.html) where `f = []` here.

> - Can you handle inhomogeneous lists as input? (e.g. 1 and "a" in one of the input lists)

There is no such thing as an *heterogeneous* list. But you can [simulate a heterogeneous list for a specific context with existential types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types#Example:_heterogeneous_lists). And then you can just use the method above to do the MapProduct.

```
*Main Control.Applicative> :i SB
data ShowBox where
  SB :: forall s. (Show s) => s -> ShowBox
    -- Defined at v.hs:1:35-36
*Main Control.Applicative> [SB 2, SB "a", SB 6.4]
[2,"a",6.4]
*Main Control.Applicative> (,) <$> [SB 2, SB "a", SB 6.4] <*> [SB 'z', SB 44]
[(2,'z'),(2,44),("a",'z'),("a",44),(6.4,'z'),(6.4,44)]
```

Answer (score 2):

It **is** possible to define a function `mapProduct` that works for any arity of function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

module MapProduct (
    mapProduct
    ) where

import Control.Monad

newtype ProdFuncList a b = ProdFuncList [ a -> b ]


class MapProdResult p where
    type MapProdArg p
    apNext :: ProdFuncList x (MapProdArg p) -> [x] -> p

instance (MapProdResult b) => MapProdResult ([a] -> b) where
    type MapProdArg ([a] -> b) = (a -> MapProdArg b)
    apNext (ProdFuncList fs) = apNext . ProdFuncList . ap fs

instance MapProdResult [b] where
    type MapProdArg [b] = b
    apNext (ProdFuncList fs) = ap fs


mapProduct :: (MapProdResult q) => (a -> MapProdArg q) -> [a] -> q
mapProduct f = apNext (ProdFuncList [f])
```

Here it is in action:

```
> :l MapProduct.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling MapProduct       ( MapProduct.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: MapProduct.
> mapProduct (+10) [1..4] :: [Int]
[11,12,13,14]
> mapProduct (*) [1..4] [10..12] :: [Int]
[10,11,12,20,22,24,30,33,36,40,44,48]
> mapProduct (\a b c -> a:b:c:[]) "bcs" "ao" "dnt" :: [String]
["bad","ban","bat","bod","bon","bot","cad","can","cat","cod","con","cot","sad","san","sat","sod","son","sot"]
```

The downside of this approach is that you'll most likely have to type annotate the result (as shown in the examples above). It would be much more idiomatic to simply use `fmap` and `ap` directly:

```
> :m + Control.Monad
> (+10) `fmap` [1..4]
[11,12,13,14]
> (*) `fmap` [1..4] `ap` [10..12]
[10,11,12,20,22,24,30,33,36,40,44,48]
> (\a b c -> a:b:c:[]) `fmap` "bcs" `ap` "ao" `ap` "dnt"
["bad","ban","bat","bod","bon","bot","cad","can","cat","cod","con","cot","sad","san","sat","sod","son","sot"]
```

This requires no type annotations, and is fully general over all monads, not just `[]`.

(The MapProduct module above could easily be generalized over all monads as well. I didn't so as to make it clearly solve the original question.)

Answer (score 1):

The function that you describe is closely related to the zipWithN functions. It will have the same type - it will just result in bigger result lists. Now the problem is that there is no way to express "a function that takes N arguments of the types `t_1, ..., t_n`" or "n lists of the types `[t_1],...,[t_n]`" (or "an n-tuple of type `([t_1], ..., [t_n]")` ) in haskell's type system (without extensions like template haskell). This is why there is not one zipWith function, but one for each number of arguments lists that is supported.

So to answer your questions:

- It is implemented by defining a function mapProductN for every number N that you want to support. For N=2 it would look like this:

  ```
  mapProduct f l1 l2 = [f x1 x2 | x1 <- l1, x2 <- x2]
  ```

  Or as a general blueprint (i.e. pseudo-code) how to define the functions for any N:

  ```
  mapProduct f l1 ... ln = [f x1 ... xn | x1 <- l1, ..., xn <- ln]
  ```
- As I said it's the same as the types of the zipWith functions, i.e.:

  ```
  zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]  
  zipWith3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]  
  zipWith4 :: (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d] -> [e]
  ```

  Since f is the first argument to the function, the type of the first argument is f's type (so for n=2 it'd be `a -> b -> c`)
- Well since it has the same type as zipWith and zipWith does something else, that'd be a no.
- Haskell doesn't allow inhomogeneous lists without an extension.
- There's an upper limit on the number of lists unless you're willing to spend the time writing infinite versions of mapProduct.

Comment: To summarize: your solution does all what was asked for except it does not handle heterogeneous input lists and variable number of arguments, right?

Comment: @levy: Right. Or well, if you enable existential types and create heterogeneous lists using them, this function will work just fine with those lists (if you also supply an existentially typed function f).

Comment: This isn't true: "Now the problem is that there is no way to express 'a function that takes N arguments ... in haskell's type system (without extensions like template haskell)." Oleg has a solution for var-args functions in Haskell '98 on his web-page.

Comment: @Porges: A variadic function is not a function that takes N arguments, it's a function that takes as many arguments as it wants. This does not help to express that the number of arguments which f takes should be equal to the number of lists given to mapProduct.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the variable arguments specifically; I should have made this more clear :) On the other hand, I wouldn't be surprised if Oleg could do this as well :P